# Clarification on statement in “Unitary Symmetry and Elementary Particles” by Lichtenberg

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, group-theory, topology, metric-space

He says that:

> The set of values of the parameter or parameters which characterize a group element can be considered to be points in some kind of space. The number of parameters characterizes the dimension of the space. We shall restrict ourselves to a *topological* space, that is, to a space in which *distance* between any two points is defined.

Where I’m confused is the topological space. How does having a topological space automatically give you a metric? Is there just a standard metric that physicists impose on this topology or does he simply mean a metric space?

I’m trying to delve into more physics that deals with abstract math so I’m not SUPER comfortable with all these topic’s, but I have learned about them previously

Comment: Perhaps this may be saying something sensible with context (though I can't figure out how), but it seems like this is just loose use of terminology. Not all topological groups are metrizable, and not all metrizable groups are Lie groups.

Answer (score 1):

You are confused because the author is misusing standard mathematical terminology.  There are topological spaces which are not metrizable.

Answer (score 0):

He is just trying to be as general as possible. That is,  the author doesn't want to restrict themselves to just metric spaces, but in general *any* space on which the notions of connectedness, continuity and convergence are defined.

> A topological space is the most general notion of a mathematical
>   space that allows for the definition of concepts such as continuity,
>   connectedness, and convergence .Other spaces, such as manifolds and
>   metric spaces, are specializations of topological spaces with extra
>   structures or constraints (cf [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space)).